# Gridstack.js not loading correctly in RequireJS using Underscore.js, jQuery, and jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, backbone.js, requirejs, gridstack

I have a problem getting [Gridstack](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/) to work in a Backbone application.

A stripped down version of the RequireJS configuration looks like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery:                       '../assets/packages/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min',
        underscore:                   'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        jqueryui:                     '../assets/packages/jqueryui/1.11.4/custom/jquery-ui.min',,
        gridstack:                    '../assets/packages/gridstack/0.2.4/gridstack.min',
    },
    shim: {
        "gridstack": {
            deps: ["jquery", "jqueryui", "underscore"],
        },
    }
});
```

The problem is that Gridstack attempts to find fetch files for Lodash and the jQueryUI components "core", "mouse", "draggable", "resizable", and "widget". See picture below.

[image]

The Backbone view file (again, boiled down) looks like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jqueryui',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'gridstack',
], function(
    $,
    jqueryui,
    _,
    Backbone,
    gridstack
    ){

    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#page"),
        className: "MyView",

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('gridstack', gridstack);
        },
    });

    return MyView;
});
```

I'm using Underscore.js (1.8.3) instead of Lodash, but that should be fine per documentation here: https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js

Is there anyway to force Gridstack to understand that all of its dependencies are already loaded?

**EDIT 2016-02-18 12:47:00**

jQueryUI is downloaded from https://jqueryui.com/download/ and includes everything except the Tooltip; it was causing problems when used with Bootstrap.

I see that many people get the AMD version of jQueryUI, e.g. through Bower. However, the package works fine for everything else, so I'm inclined to think the problem lies with Gridstack.

Comment: I've answered this on the GitHub page: https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/issues/332

Answer (score 0):

While the problem with Gridstack lingers and the author of Gridstack does not intend to fully support RequireJS (https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/issues/332), I found an alternative solution called **[Gridster](http://gridster.net/)**.

Comment: Basically gridstack is alternative to gridster :) I've started gridstack because gridster wasn't developing anymore and doesn't work well with bootstrap 3 etc...

This is how I use requirejs and it works for me http://take.ms/aTQkM

Comment: for development I don't use minified versions of js libs and then build one js file using almondjs and minify it. The result js file includes only needed files from jq ui, etc. No need to take whole jq ui which is so huge

Comment: Please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582945/redundant-dependencies-with-requirejs

Answer (score 0):

For the jquery-ui not found errors I had to use map in my require.config to map all the files to a single file

```
paths: {
    "jquery": "path/to/jquery-3.2.1.min",
    "jquery-ui": "path/to/jquery-ui.min",
    "gridstack": "path/to/gridstack",
},
map: {
    'c/gridstack.jQueryUI': {
        'jquery-ui/data': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/disable-selection': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/focusable': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/form': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/ie': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/keycode': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/labels': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/jquery-1-7': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/plugin': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/safe-active-element': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/safe-blur': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/scroll-parent': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/tabbable': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/unique-id': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/version': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/widget': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/widgets/mouse': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/widgets/draggable': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/widgets/droppable': 'jquery-ui',
        'jquery-ui/widgets/resizable': 'jquery-ui',
    }
}
```