# Redundant dependencies with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs, shared-libraries

My problem is with having redundant RequireJS dependencies that point to the same JS library.

The referenced library is **jQuery UI**, it's referenced both internally and by external library **Gridstack**, which is causing this issue.

Both internal and external references should point to ONE file `jquery-ui.js`.

How to configure RequireJS (i.e. inside `main.js`) to handle these references as one without doing any changes to any of the existing modules/libraries?

- [JQuery UI v1.11.2](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js) - My JQuery UI distribution (single file)
- [Gridstack 0.2.5-dev](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/blob/master/src/gridstack.js) - The library that references it as `jquery-ui/core`, `jquery-ui/widget`, `jquery-ui/mouse`, `jquery-ui/draggable` and `jquery-ui/resizable`
- I use `jquery.ui` internally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Louis' answer pointed me in the right direction, it still took me some time to figure out the complete solution, so I'm posting my working requirejs config here for future reference:

```
requirejs.config( {

    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min',

        'jquery.ui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min',

        lodash: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min',
        gridstack: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.3.0/gridstack.min',
        'gridstack.jqueryui': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.3.0/gridstack.jQueryUI.min',

    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery-ui/data': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/disable-selection': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/focusable': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/form': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/ie': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/keycode': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/labels': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/jquery-1-7': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/plugin': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/safe-active-element': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/safe-blur': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/scroll-parent': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/tabbable': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/unique-id': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/version': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/widget': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/widgets/mouse': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/widgets/draggable': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/widgets/droppable': 'jquery.ui',
            'jquery-ui/widgets/resizable': 'jquery.ui',
        }
    },
} );

require( ['dashhub'] );
```

Note that I could not seem to get it working with the `gridstack.all.js` script from cdnjs. This means in your modules you must reference both `gridstack` and `gridstack.jqueryui`in the define command.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the `jquery-ui.js` file you are trying to load, I see that it is a combination of a multiple functions that could be in separate files **and** that it calls `define` only once. So it registers as a single module. This is important to know because if it had called `define` for each of `jquery-ui/mouse`, `jquery-ui/draggable`, etc. then the solution would be different because then we'd be talking about a single jQuery UI file that contains multiple modules.

Ok, so this being established, what you can do is use a `map` in your RequireJS configuration. I'm assuming you already have a proper `paths` configuration that allows loading the `jquery-ui.js` file as the `jquery.ui` module. Add this map:

```
map: {
    '*': {
        'jquery-ui/mouse': 'jquery.ui',
        'jquery-ui/draggable': 'jquery.ui',
        // And so on for all different cases...
    }
}
```

This says in all modules (`*`) whenever `jquery-ui/mouse` is requested, then load `jquery.ui` instead, and so on for all the other modules that will be listed under `*`.